# Filter nginx log files

Tags: nginx, logfile

I have many nginx access log files and i want to parse these files between two dates.
 For example i want to parse the log files between 15/Sep/2020 until 15/Oct/2020 and i use this command:

```
zcat /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.access.log.*.gz | awk '$4 >= "[15/Sep/2020" && $4 < "[15/Oct/2020"'
```

or this command:

```
zcat /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.access.log.*.gz | sed -n -e '/15\/Sep\/2020/,/15\/Oct\/2020/p'
```

but the result is not between two dates.
Please help me for this. 
Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into NGINX logging to syslog, and reading logs with `journalctl` on SystemD-enabled servers. Then you don't need any fancy `sed` or `awk` to look at specific times.

Comment: Thank you for comment. so how am i gonna do that with `journalctl`?

Comment: Example: `journalctl --since "2015-06-26 23:15:00" --until "2015-06-26 23:20:00"`. NGINX would be configured, e.g. `access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log`